# how to select underside image view in java?

Tags: java, xml

i have two imageview on eachother. under image is my photo and top image in my border. now I want to be able to click under imageView. but I cant because the top imageView(border) is on top.

```java
<FrameLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/underImage"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="0.8"
     android:layout_margin="50dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:scaleType="centerInside" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/topImage"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

</FrameLayout>
```